# Repetitive Indexing for certain IDs

Tags: powerbi

Is there a way in Power BI to index a group of repetitive IDs?

For example, below is an illustrative data set with Date, City, and State. I want to be able to index every time Florida (FL) appears, but if the earlier City was also in FL, then I don't want the index to change. I included a column with the desired outcome.

The reason I am asking this is because I want to be able to know if the location is currently in FL, and if it is in FL, how long it's been there. With the use of index, I can easily find the answer. If you think of a different solution, I would be more than happy to hear of an alternative answer rather than first indexing.

[image]

Comment: For time calculation you would need to dates (In & Out), then you may use separate date tables to slice your visit data as your need.

Comment: how is the table ordered?